# Load file without a button click javascript or jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

In the next javascript code i have a function to open a file(xml) and then it will search for all the occurences that are between a specific tag(`<file>`). After using a Regex expression to get the filenames, i need that the dialog can be open, automatically, the same number of times of the files discovered in the xml file. The objective is to force the user to search in their local directory for the files that are in the xml file. After this i will send the strings to the server side.

```
function fileSelected(evt) {

        var files = evt.target.files;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var bol;


        if (document.getElementById("fileToLoad").value == "") {
            alert("Please select a file before submitting.");
            bol = 0;
        }
        else {
            ext = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").value;
            fpath = ext;
            ext = ext.substring(ext.length - 3, ext.length);
            ext = ext.toLowerCase();
            if (ext == 'xml')
                bol = 1;
            else if (ext == 'rdf')
                bol = 1;
            else {
                alert("You selected a ." + ext + " file; this is not allowed.");
                bol = 0;
            }
        }
        if (bol == 1) {

            reader.onload = function (event) {
                editor.setValue(event.target.result);
                var teste = editor.getValue();
                getFileName(teste);
                var debug = event.target.files;
                document.getElementById("Procura").style.visibility = "visible";
                //document.getElementById('<%=hf.ClientID%>').value = editor.getValue();
            }
            reader.readAsText(files[0], "UTF-8");
        }
        return false;
    }


        function getFileName(str) {
        var matches = str.match(/<file>(.*)<\/file>/g);
        var len = matches.length, i, result;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            matches[i] = matches[i].replace(/<[\/]{0,1}(file|FILE)[^><]*>/g, "");
            //need to open dialog for user to search for the same file in matches[i]
            //after get file, will save on a string in order to send to server
        }
    }
```

I´ve tried many things but this is my first steps in this world(js/jquery/html).

Comment: So if there are 10 occurrence of a `<file>` tag, then the user is going to see 10 dialog boxes? Or am I misreading `After using a Regex expression to get the filenames, i need that the dialog can be open, automatically, the same number of times of the files discovered in the xml file.`?

Comment: Yes, it will ask the user 10 times for search for the specific file. The best way of doing this is to getting the files without asking anything to the user. Unfortunately i only have the fakedirectory (fakedirectory/file.xml) of the xml file, so i don´t know how to get all the needed files(that are between the <file> tag) directly from the code. All the files are in the same directory as the file.xml. :/